# Dates (Duration) in Google Sheets Script

Tags: date, scripting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with three columns:
 - Date and time (timestamp)
 - Duration
 - Description

I have an script that when I write something in 'Description', inserts in 'Date' the date and time at this moment, and the 'Duration':

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Sheet2" ) {
    var col = e.source.getActiveCell().getColumn();
    if(col == 3 ) {
      // I'm in column three
      var cellTimeStamp = e.range.offset(0,-2); // First column of the same row
      var cellTimeDiff = e.range.offset(0,-1); // Second column of the same row
      var cellTimePrev = e.range.offset(-1,-2); // First column of the previous row

      var timeTimeStamp = new Date();
      var iniTime = cellTimePrev.getValue().getTime();
      var finTime = timeTimeStamp.getTime() ;
      var timeDiff = String(finTime - iniTime) ;


      cellTimeStamp.setValue(timeTimeStamp);  

      cellTimeDiff.setValue(timeDiff); // [***]


    }
  }    
}
```

When this executes (as an event) in the column of 'Duration' there is NOT something in the format of 'HH:mm:ss'.

But if I remove the last line in this script and adds this formulae in the sheet:
  =A3-A2 (in row 3)
  =A4-A3 (in row 4)
  ...
then it works ok.

I'd like to know how to meet the same result but with a script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note, the format for a duration is `[hh]:mm:ss`.  I don't think this has ever been written down, I had to get it by using `range.getNumberFormat()`

Comment: It is source code in a Google Spreadsheet.  Now I use a formulae (=A4-A3), not the source code in this solution.

Comment: My formula still subtracts two date times, but originally I was formatting the output cell with `hh:mm:ss` which was fine providing the difference was under a day.  I had to figure out how to show the duration once the differences exceeded a day.  I wish Google would just document `Range::setNumberFormat()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timeDiff is the result of `finTime - iniTime` which are both [native date object values](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date), which means we have milliseconds .

converting that in hh:mm:ss is simple math... : 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour... 
A simple code could be like this :

```
function msToTime(s) {
  var ms = s % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

  return hrs + ':' + mins + ':' + secs; // milliSecs are not shown but you can use ms if needed
}
```

If you prefer formating your string more conventionally (2 digits for each value) don't forget you can use [Utilities.formatString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(String,Object...)) to do so.

example below :

```
  return Utilities.formatString("%02d",hrs) + ':' + Utilities.formatString("%02d",mins) + ':' + Utilities.formatString("%02d",secs);
```

---

### EDIT

Following your comment :

Spreadsheets are smarter than you think, you can try the code below and you will see that the result is actually a time value.(check by double clicking on it)

```
function test() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var t1 = sh.getRange('a1').getValue().getTime();
  var t2 = sh.getRange('b1').getValue().getTime();
  sh.getRange('c1').setValue(msToTime(t1-t2)).setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss');

}

function msToTime(s) {
  var ms = s % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

  return hrs + ':' + mins + ':' + secs; // milliSecs are not shown but you can use ms if needed
}
```

**note** that `setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss')` is optional, it's only there to force the spreadsheet to display `hour:min:sec` format but automatic mode works as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

In fact, I was not looking for a string, but a number or date.

When I make the substraction in the sheet (as a formulae), I get a number.  And the, I format it from the menu Format.

But if I make the substraction from the script, I can not get the same number (or date).

This is my problem.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: see edit please, my answer returns what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works nice !!

I had not understood your solution, I'm very sorry.