# Finding the Date that matches the condition in a loop of another column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet which contains multiple columns, one of the column is date (it is column F and is sorted from oldest to latest)and another column(G) is time duration values. I made a condition whenever a combination of three durations is taken if it is greater than 10 hours, the respective combination is took and the oldest date in the combination is taken as reference to another program. This combination should be of the latest one ( I mean by date). The code  I have tried is

```
function calculation(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName("10017135ASR");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var time = sheet.getRange('G1:G'+lastRow).getValues();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('F1:F'+lastRow).getValues();
  var range1 = sheet.getRange('H1:H'+lastRow).setValues(time).setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
  var refer = sheet.getRange('N2').setValue("10:00").setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm");
  var refer1= refer.getValue();
  var range = range1.getValues();
  var time = sheet.getRange('H1:H');
  time.setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm'); 
  sheet.getRange('I2:I'+lastRow).setValue('0').setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
  var one= sheet.getRange('H'+(lastRow)).getValue();
  sheet.getRange('I'+lastRow).setValue(one).setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
  var two = sheet.getRange('H'+(lastRow-1)).getValue();
  sheet.getRange('I'+(lastRow-1)).setValue(two).setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
  loop1:
    for (var i = lastRow-3; i>0; i--){
     var value1 = range[i][0];
     var V2 = sheet.getRange('K'+lastRow).setValue(value1).setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm");
     var L2 = sheet.getRange('J'+lastRow).setFormula("=LARGE(I2:I,1)").setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
     var L3= sheet.getRange('J'+(lastRow-1)).setFormula("=LARGE(I2:I,2)").setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
     var sum = sheet.getRange('M2').setFormula("=SUM(J2:J)").setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm");
     var vB= sum.getValue();
     var V1 = V2.getValue(); 
     var sum2 = vB + V1;
       if((vB)>= refer1){
        sheet.getRange('L2').setValue(sum2).setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');   
        var da=sheet.getRange('F'+(i+2)).getValue();
        sheet.getRange('N2').setValue(da).setNumberFormat('DD-mm-yyyy');
        break loop1;
        }   
       else {
         sheet.getRange('I'+(i+1)).setValue(value1).setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
       } 
     }
   }
```

Here I am not getting output,the loop ends at first row, Even though there is no need to go the first row.Since the required output is at row number 30 and the respective date is 30/7/2020.
The worksheet is shown below
[image]

The results obtained is
[image]

Comment: What is the desired output? You want to retrieve the oldest date and the total duration of the **first** three-cell combination whose duration is greater than 10 hours? And where do you want to write this data to?

Comment: @lamblichus I need the latest combination of 10 hours  or more and in that combination the oldest date.here in above example the combination is 3 30 ,3 ,4 hrs and date is 30/7/2020

Comment: I understand you need the latest combination of 10 hours or more. I meant to ask exactly what data do you need. The durations of the three cells, separately, and the oldest date? Or maybe the total duration (the sum of the three cells?). And what do you want to do with this data? Write it to some other cells?

Comment: Or you're just asking how to retrieve this data, and there's no need to write it back to the spreadsheet?

Comment: @lamblichus Exactly I need duration of these three cells separately in three locations and sum of these in another location and the respective dates. All these results to be in the same sheet. I have almost 120 similar sheets and I am using all these results for another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Working with durations:

Working with sheets durations in Apps Script is a bit messy: see [Working With Durations In Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137061/working-with-durations-in-google-apps-script).

When retrieved via Apps Script, a duration becomes a JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), based on the zero mark for date/time in Google Sheets (`12/30/1899 0:00:00`) (see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87187)).

In JS, in order to compare the dates, you can use [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), which returns the number of milliseconds since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which refers to `1 January 1970`. Therefore, a date retrieved from a sheet duration will result in a negative number of milliseconds. In order to avoid problems with this, you can use a reference date every time you compare dates. One option would be to set a sheets cell to `00:00` duration and use that value as reference. That's what I did in the sample below, in cell `N3`.

#### Workflow:

- Set `N3` to the reference duration (`00:00`) and `N2` to `10:00`.
- Loop through all the durations in `G2:G`, using an array (`comboData`) to store the possible combination of durations. For each element, (1) check if `comboData` has less than 3 elements, and add current element if that's the case, (2) otherwise, find the minimum in `comboData`, check if current element is higher, and replace if that's the case, (3) calculate total duration of current combination, and break loop if it's higher than `10:00`.
- Transform the duration from milliseconds to your desired duration format (using the function `msToHMS(ms)` below, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25974725) by [Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368381/serge-insas)), and write it to the sheet, using `setValue()` for the total duration, and `setValues()` for the three durations and dates.

#### Code sample:

```
function getCombinationRowIndex() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName("10017135ASR");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var reference = sheet.getRange('N3').setValue('00:00').setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm').getValue().getTime();
  var sourceData = sheet.getRange('F2:G' + lastRow).getValues().reverse().map(row => [row[1].getTime() - reference, row[0]]);
  var limit = sheet.getRange('N2').setValue("10:00").setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm").getValue().getTime() - reference;
  var comboData = []; // Array to store the combination
  var totalDuration = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    var row = sourceData[i];
    if (comboData.length < 3) comboData.push(row); // If combination has less than 3 elements, add current element
    else {
      var minimum = Math.min(...comboData.map(val => val[0])); // Find minimum in current combination
      var index = comboData.findIndex(val => val[0] == minimum); // Find index for minimum in current combination
      if (row[0] > minimum) comboData[index] = row; // Replace minimum if current element is higher
    }
    totalDuration = comboData.reduce(((acc, combo) => acc + combo[0]), 0); // Total duration in milliseconds
    if (totalDuration > limit && comboData.length === 3) break; // If total duration is higher than 10 hours, break loop
  }
  sheet.getRange("K2:L4").setValues(comboData.map(combo => [msToHMS(combo[0]), combo[1]])); // Write combo data to K2:L4
  var formattedDuration = msToHMS(totalDuration); // Total duration (formatted hh:mm:ss)
  sheet.getRange("J2").setValue(formattedDuration); // Write total duration to J2
}

function msToHMS(ms) {
  var seconds = ms / 1000;
  var hours = parseInt( seconds / 3600 ); // 3,600 seconds in 1 hour
  seconds = seconds % 3600; // seconds remaining after extracting hours
  var minutes = parseInt( seconds / 60 ); // 60 seconds in 1 minute
  seconds = seconds % 60;
  return Utilities.formatString("%02d",hours) + ':' + Utilities.formatString("%02d",minutes) + ':' + Utilities.formatString("%02d",seconds);
}
```

[image]

#### Notes:

- Only the data in columns `F`, `G` and `N` is needed for this sample. No need for `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, `M`, etc.

Comment: @lamblichus it says val.getTime() is not a function {line 5}

Comment: @KumaraGuru Your values in column G are durations right? I'm not getting any error. Did you copy the full code as it is?

Comment: @KumaraGuru I'd suggest you to share the spreadsheet you're working on.

Comment: @lamblichus I copied the above code as it is But the system on running says Typeerror val.getTime() is not a function

Comment: This is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z946mI6mznuJ44yMhwtePbSPvqco3IDfvVcEH2MZT_A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KumaraGuru Alright problem was you have headers, and of course that's not a date but a string, and doesn't have a `getTime()` function. I fixed that in my answer so it retrieves the range `G2:G` instead of `G1:G`. With this change, it doesn't show any error, using a copy of your document. I also changed the reference cell from `N1` to `N3`, since you have a header on `N1`. Let me know if that works for you now.

Comment: @lamblichus I got result as 10 in N2 and 0 in N3. there is no other data. I need to get in this Sheet which all durations corresponds to 10 hrs or more and their dates. if possible set the individual durations in any three cells (K2:K4 preferably) and dates (L2:L4) total durations in J2

Comment: @lamblichus I added lines to take the results in column except comboDurations as I was not able to map the result .But as per the sheet shared the total duration is 10:30 and oldest date is 30/7/2020 here I am getting 11:00 and 28/7/2020

Comment: @KumaraGuru I edited the code sample so that it writes the three durations and dates to `K2:L4`, and the total duration to `J2`. About you last comment, though, I don't understand what you mean, because the sheet `10017135ASR` has its first (latest) combination on 28/07, 29/07, 30/07, with a total duration of 11 hours (4, 3, 4). And that's the outcome I'm getting. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @lamblichus three durations need not be a consecutive rows. Here the total duration equal to 10 or more occurs when  3/8/2020,31/7/2020,30/7/2020 and the durations are 3:30,3:00,4:00 so total is 10:30. U get it right.

Comment: @KumaraGuru My apologies, I had totally misunderstood that part of your question. I updated my answer, now it should work. At least, I'm getting the results you expect. I hope this finally works for you.

Comment: The code works fine But when i apply this another sheet named 10017135RSR there is a small glitch facing and it says "The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 3" I am sharing the link of the sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z946mI6mznuJ44yMhwtePbSPvqco3IDfvVcEH2MZT_A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KumaraGuru It was failing if the 10 hours were reached before having 3 elements in the combo. I fixed that by adding the condition `comboData.length === 3` before breaking the loop. My guess is that you want a three-element combo even if one element is already above 10 hours, but let me know if that's the case. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @lamblichus Yes what you have guessed is correct. I need a 3 duration combo whatever the durations be and checking the sum whether it is greater than 10 or not.

Comment: @KumaraGuru I had forgot to update the answer. Now this condition has been added to the code sample and it should work for this other sheet too. Let me know if that works.